# How to search all the commits starting from given commit ?

Tags: git

I know git rev-list but it gives all commits which happened before given commit. How do I find out all commits that happened after a specific commit?

Comment: Did you even try to look at the man page for `rev-list` before asking? It very clearly shows the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git rev-list ABC..
```

will display all the commits after commit `ABC` (not included).